# Bad shipping options provided by Paypal checkout

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am having an issue with paypal express checkout integration in Magento. Customers who click "checkout with paypal" in our cart get taken to a paypal login page. After they login to paypal, paypal sends a calback to magento with their address to pull shipping options.

For some reason, paypal is receiving weird shipping options from magento in addition to the regular methods. They have names like "no rate" and are listed as costing $0.00.

I can't find any information on where paypal gets shipping methods from or how to limit them. I am working with paypal support, but the issue seems to be with magento.

Does anyone know where these shipping methods might come from and/or how to limit the shipping methods offered by paypal?

*update*
Paypal support has confirmed that this is a magento issue. Magento is passing the following bad options to them:

```
shippingoptionamount "0.00" "8.95" "23.32" "35.28" "73.91" "0.00"
shippingoptionname "customshippingrate_customshippingrate" "flatrate_flatrate" "fedex_GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY" "fedex_FEDEX_2_DAY" "fedex_PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT" "no_rate"
```

I have been trying to identify exactly where Magento pulls its shipping method list from, but so far it still eludes me.

Comment: Bump.  I have the same issue on a Magento 1.7.0.2 site I inherited.

Comment: It's the same issue with 1.9

Comment: I never figured this out. I think I ended up with ugly code to hide the option in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment but to make sure it stays (and gets noticed), I've answered this problem on the Magento Stack here with a module to fix it;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/paypal-express-shipping-methods/50290#50290